# helm-bibtex actions: copy to separate file and delete entry + associated pdf

Tags: org-ref, bibtex, helm-bibtex

I am having difficulty creating specific helm-bibtex actions, and I think that more examples of existent actions in the [docs](https://github.com/tmalsburg/helm-bibtex#create-new-actions) would help.

Namely, I would like to develop actions that:

1. copy/move several selected entries from one bib file to another. The name of the destination bib file could be entered via a prompt.
2. Remove selected entries and the associated pdf (if available) from a bib file.

I think that this type of operations are quite standard and useful, specially when dealing with large bibliographies. I'm actually surprised that they are not included by default in helm-bibtex. Thanks.